# Ubuntu freezes for 44 seconds every 8 minutes

Tags: server, apache2

I am stuck on a problem and am wondering if you have any ideas.

I have sites on an Ubuntu server in Sydney with RackSpace.

Every 8 minutes, without fail, the server hangs for 44 seconds.

The interesting thing is that the freezing is related to an IP address. If I am on my computer, the first time I go to a site it will hang for 44 seconds, then start up and work fine for 8 minutes. Then it will hang for another 44 seconds. If I am on another computer, with the same IP address, it will hang at the same time. But if someone else is on a different IP address, it will do the same thing, but hang at a different time. So you may be on a site and it will hang and I can refresh a page just fine, and when it hangs for me you may be able to access a site no problem.

If I do continuous pinging, it doesn't record any spike during a hang. There's nothing unsual when I do a trace root during a hang.

I have checked the number of processes during a hang using pstree and its all fine.

There's no spike in disk usage, memory or CPU.

Interestingly, when it hangs on my IP address I can still access the server via ftp and upload or download files.

I can't see any kind of time out / max session setting in the apache2 config file.

I'm all out of ideas. I wonder if anyone has any suggestions as to what I could look at.

Just for the record, I wrote a wee PHP script to refresh a page every second and record when it freezes and how long for. Here's the recent log:

```
               After 530 seconds - freezed for 43 seconds - 12:43:55 pm
               After 531 seconds - freezed for 43 seconds - 12:35:05 pm
               After 493 seconds - freezed for 44 seconds - 12:26:14 pm
               After 472 seconds - freezed for 44 seconds - 12:18:01 pm
               After 482 seconds - freezed for 43 seconds - 12:10:09 pm
```

Any ideas? I'd appreciate any thoughts you have.

Cheers and thanks,

Jeff

jeff@firefly.co.nz

Comment: Congratulations, you got one of those mind breaking problems which are difficult to solve but you feel very pleased once you troubleshoot, diagnose and solve it. I'm sorry I can only help you with some encouragement instead of advice. In the meantime... 1. Is it a fresh installation? 2. Does it happen all time after a reboot? 3. Have you considered plotting some bootcharts and look for any suspicious pattern? (I think you can delay them and it is not mandatory to be a _boot_ chart)

Comment: It could be intermediate problems like some transparent http proxy, or the server itself. Can you ssh into the machine and observe load with `htop` during the freeze time? Does the same problem happen with https?

Comment: Could be something simple like the swappiness needing tuned.

Comment: I wonder if there is a DNS timeout involved here. At one time I traced similar issues to my ISP slow DNS, so I changed my DNS servers to external IP addresses and sped things up.